Proof verification of the validity of a formula for the gcd-sum function
Define  $P: \mathbb{N} \setminus\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as $$P(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \gcd(k,n) .$$
I want to prove that, for $n\geq 2$, if the factorization of $n$ into distinct primes is $n= p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2} …p_s^{\alpha_s} $ then:
$$ P(n) = \prod_{j=1}^s [ (\alpha_j+1)p_j^{\alpha_j} - \alpha_j p_j^{\alpha_j -1}] $$
Step 1 If $p$ is prime, then $P(p) = 2p-1$.
Step 2 If $p$ is prime and $k$ is a positive integer, then $P(p^k) = (k+1)p^k -kp^{k-1} $.
Step 3 P is multiplicative: if $m$ and $n$ are coprime positive integers, then $P(mn) = P(m)P(n)$.
Let’s prove the three steps.
Step 1 If $p$ is prime, then $P(p) = 2p-1$.
If $p$ is prime, indeed $P(p) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^p \gcd(k,p) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \gcd(k,p) + \gcd(p,p) = (p-1) + p = 2p-1.$
Step 2 If $p$ is prime and $k$ is a positive integer, then $P(p^k) = (k+1)p^k -kp^{k-1} $.
We’ll prove this by induction. The base case with $k=1$ is true, as shown in step 1. Let’s now assume that $P(p^k) = (k+1)p^k -kp^{k-1} $ and let’s try to calculate $P(p^{k+1})$.
$$P(p^{k+1}) = \displaystyle\sum_{h=1}^{p^{k+1}} \gcd(h, p^{k+1})= \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{p-1} \displaystyle\sum_{h=j p^k +1}^{(j+1) p^k} \gcd(h, p^{k+1})$$
Now, every inner sum is the same except for the last one which instead of ending with $p^k$, ends with a $p^{k+1}$. Because of this I add and subtract $p^k$ to have every one of the $p$ blocks be the same:
$$ \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{p-1} \displaystyle\sum_{h=j p^k +1}^{(j+1) p^k} \gcd(h, p^{k+1})= \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{p-1} \displaystyle\sum_{h=j p^k +1}^{(j+1) p^k} \gcd(h, p^{k+1}) + p^{k} - p^k = \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\displaystyle\sum_{h=1}^{p^k} \gcd(h, p^{k+1}) + p^{k+1}- p^k$$
Now, since the numbers $h$ in the inner sum don’t exceed $p^k$, the gcd is gonna be the same if i swap $p^{k+1}$ with $p^k$. Also the terms don’t depend on $j$ anymore so i can sum over it:
$$ p \cdot \displaystyle\sum_{h=1}^{p^k} \gcd(h, p^{k}) + p^{k+1}- p^k$$
Using the inductive hypothesis, this is equal to:
$$ p \cdot ((k+1)p^k -kp^{k-1} ) + p^{k+1} - p^k$$
And with a bit of algebra, this is equal to:
$$ (k+2) p^{k+1} - (k+1)p^k$$
which was what we wanted :)
Step 3 P is multiplicative: if $m$ and $n$ are coprime positive integers, then $P(mn) = P(m)P(n)$.
Suppose $m$ and $n$ are two coprime positive integers. Then for the Chinese Remainder Theorem we have:
$$ P(mn) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{mn} \gcd(k,mn) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{mn} \gcd(k,m) \gcd(k,n) $$
Now let’s group these terms $m$ by $m$. we get n subsets of m terms each:
$$ \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{mn} \gcd(k,m) \gcd(k,n) = \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^m \gcd( jm + l, m) \gcd( jm + l, n)$$
Now, of course:
$$ \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^m \gcd( jm + l, m) \gcd( jm + l, n) =  \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^m \gcd( l, m) \gcd( jm + l, n) $$
Now let’s exchange the sums and then take out common factors:
$$ \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^m \gcd( l, m) \gcd( jm + l, n) = \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^m \gcd(l,m) \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \gcd(jm+l,n)$$
And now, since for any $l \in \mathbb{Z}$ and any $m$ coprime with $n$, $[j] \mapsto [jm+l]$ is a bijection in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$, we can see that the inner sum is just $\gcd(1,n) + \gcd(2,n) + … + 
\gcd(n,n)$ scrambled around. So we have:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^m \gcd(l,m) \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \gcd(jm+l,n) = \displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^m \gcd(l,m) \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n} \gcd(j,n)$$
which is $P(m)P(n)$, what we wanted.
My questions are:

Does this look correct?
I’m sure there’s a simpler way…


For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Here we use some basic facts of arithmetical functions, i.e. functions from $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$ and show this way the claim. We want to show that the arithmetical function $P$ defined as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{P(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \gcd(k,n)\qquad n\geq 1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
is multiplicative, i.e. $P(mn)=P(m)P(n)$ if $m,n$ are coprime and that $P$ can be written for $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_s^{\alpha_s}$ as product
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{P(n)
=\prod_{j=1}^s\left(\left(\alpha_j+1\right)p_j^{\alpha_j}-\alpha_jp_j^{\alpha_j-1}\right)\qquad n\geq 1}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
In order to use the machinery for arithmetical functions conveniently we look for a representation of $P$ as divisor sum $\sum_{d|n}$. Given the set $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ we can partition it into pairwise disjoint subsets by setting
\begin{align*}
S_{d}=\left\{x\frac{n}{d} : 1\leq x\leq d, \ \gcd(x,d)=1\right\}
\end{align*}
and get
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[n]=\bigcup_{d|n}S_{d}}
\end{align*}
For a proof of this relationship see  for instance Lemma 1.4 in Introduction to Arithmetical Functions by P. J. McCarthy. It might be helpful to see an example. If we take $n=10$ we have
\begin{align*}
{\color{blue}{S_{d}}}&=\left\{x\frac{10}{d} : 1\leq x\leq d, \ \gcd(x,d)=1\right\}\\
{\color{blue}{S_{1}}}&=\left\{10x: 1\leq x\leq 1,\ \gcd(x,1)=1\right\}{\color{blue}{=\{10\}}}\\
{\color{blue}{S_{2}}}&=\left\{5x: 1\leq x\leq 2,\ \gcd(x,2)=1\right\}{\color{blue}{=\{5\}}}\\
{\color{blue}{S_{5}}}&=\left\{2x: 1\leq x\leq 5,\ \gcd(x,5)=1\right\}{\color{blue}{=\{2,4,6,8\}}}\\
{\color{blue}{S_{10}}}&=\left\{x: 1\leq x\leq 10,\ \gcd(x,10)=1\right\}{\color{blue}{=\{1,3,7,9\}}}\\
\end{align*}
Note, that the cardinality of $S_{d}$ is $\Phi(d)$ , where $\Phi$ is Euler's totient function.
We can now write $P$ more conveniently as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{P(n)}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\gcd(k,n)=\sum_{d|n}\sum_{k\in S_{d}}\gcd(k,n)\\
&=\sum_{d|n}\sum_{k\in S_{d}} \frac{n}{d}\\
&=\sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\left|S_{d}\right|\\
&\color{blue}{=\sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\Phi(d)}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
We have with (4) a promising presentation but we need also some preliminaries to continue smoothly. At first it's helpful to use the operator $\star$ to denote the Dirichlet Convolution
\begin{align*}
(f\star g)(n)=\sum_{d|n}f(d)g(n/d)
\end{align*}
With this notation (4) can be written as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{P=\Phi\star \zeta_1}\tag{5}
\end{align*}
where $\zeta_k(n):= n^k$. It is not hard to show that both, $\Phi$ as well as $\zeta_k$ are multiplicative arithmetical functions.
Multiplicative property of $P$: We recall the convolution of multiplicative arithmetical functions is again a multiplicative arithmetical function. Since $\Phi$ and $\zeta_1$ are multiplicative arithmetical functions it follows from (5) immediately that also $P$ is multiplicative. (For a proof of this property of multiplicative functions see e.g. Proposition 1.6 in McCarthy's book.)
Product formula of $P$: In order to show the product representation (2) of $P$ we recall the relation
\begin{align*}
n=\sum_{d|n}\Phi(d)
\end{align*}
which can be written using Dirichlet convolution as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\zeta_1=\Phi\star\zeta}\tag{6}
\end{align*}
where $\zeta:=\zeta_0$ is given as $\zeta_0(n)=1$ for all positive natural numbers $n$. We need two more elementary arithmetical functions in order to show the multiplicative property of $P$. There is the neutral element $\delta$, namely the arithmetical function
\begin{align*}
\delta(n)=\begin{cases}
1\qquad& n=1\\
0\qquad& \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
so that
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f\star \delta = f=\delta\star f}
\end{align*}
It is not difficult to show that arithmetic functions $f$ with $f(1)\ne 0$ have an inverse $f^{-1}$, so that these functions form an abelian group with respect to $\star$.
We also use the Möbius function $\mu$
which is the inverse of the $zeta$ function, so that
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\zeta\star\mu=\delta=\mu\star\zeta}\tag{7}
\end{align*}
We obtain from (6) and (7)
\begin{align*}\
\color{blue}{\zeta_1\star\mu}
&=\left(\Phi \star \zeta\right)\star\mu
=\Phi\star\left(\zeta\star\mu\right)
=\Phi\star\delta\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\Phi}
\end{align*}
Putting this into (5) and evaluating it at $p^{\alpha}$ (this is sufficient, since we already know that $P$ is multiplicative), we get using commutativity and associativity of the Dirichlet convolution:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{P\left(p^{\alpha}\right)}
&=\left(\Phi\star \zeta_1\right)\left(p^{\alpha}\right)\\
&=\left(\left(\zeta_1\star\mu\right)\star\zeta_1\right)\left(p^{\alpha}\right)\\
&=\left(\mu\star\left(\zeta_1\star\zeta_1\right)\right)\left(p^{\alpha}\right)\\
&=\sum_{d|p^{\alpha}}\mu(d)\left(\zeta_1\star\zeta_1\right)\left(p^{\alpha}/d\right)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\alpha}\mu\left(p^{j}\right)\left(\zeta_1\star\zeta_1\right)\left(p^{\alpha-j}\right)\\
&=\mu(1)\left(\zeta_1\star\zeta_1\right)\left(p^{\alpha}\right)
+\mu(p)\left(\zeta_1\star\zeta_1\right)\left(p^{\alpha-1}\right)+0+\cdots+0\\
&\color{blue}{=\left(\zeta_1\star\zeta_1\right)\left(p^{\alpha}\right)
-\left(\zeta_1\star\zeta_1\right)\left(p^{\alpha-1}\right)}
\end{align*}
and since
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\left(\zeta_1\star\zeta_1\right)\left(p^{\alpha}\right)}
&=\sum_{d|p^{\alpha}}\zeta_1(d)\zeta_1\left(\frac{p^{\alpha}}{d}\right)\\
&=\sum_{d|p^{\alpha}}d\cdot\frac{p^{\alpha}}{d}\\
&=p^{\alpha}\sum_{d|p^{\alpha}}1\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=(\alpha+1)p^{\alpha}}
\end{align*}
the claim (2) follows.
